# Function types in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand function types in Go, so I tried with the below code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func myfn1(i string) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func myfunc2(firstName string, lastName string) string {
    return "Hello "+ firstName + " " + lastName + "!"
}

func test(do func(string), val string) {
    do(val)
}

func test1(t func(string,string), fname string, lname string) string {
  opt := t(fname, lname)
  return opt
}

func main() {
    test(myfn1, "Aishu")
    greet := test1(myfunc2, "Aishu","S")
    fmt.Println(greet)
}
```

And it throws below error.

> 1. t(fname, lname) used as value
> 2. cannot use myfunc2 (type func(string, string) string) as type func(string, string) in argument to test1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9Dw3AxrfNq1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function types are described in [Golang Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types) as:

> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same
>   parameter and result types.

Here it is clearly mentioned that function with `same parameter and result types`

There are different functions definition that you are passing to your main program and the definitions that your function requires. If you look at below function carefully you have passed `t` as argument to `test1` which returns nothing but you are assign its value to `opt` that's why the error.

> t(fname, lname) used as value

For second error which says:

> cannot use myfunc2 (type func(string, string) string) as type
>   func(string, string) in argument to test1

Since because if you look at the type of function you are passing to `test1` as an argument and the type of argument that you have defined in `test1` are different.

Please check below working code.

```
package main

import "fmt"


func myfn1(i string) {
    fmt.Println(i)
}

func myfunc2(firstName string, lastName string) string{

return "Hello "+ firstName + " " + lastName + "!"


}

func test(do func(string), val string){
do(val)
}


func test1(t func(string,string) string, fname string, lname string) string{

  opt := t(fname,lname)
  return opt
}


func main() {
    test(myfn1, "Aishu")
     greet := test1(myfunc2, "Aishu","S")
     fmt.Println(greet)

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pwz04TucwZ3) example

Answer (score 4):

You have two unrelated problems.

The first:

> 1. t(fname, lname) used as value

Is that you're trying to assign the return value of `t(fname, lname)` to a variable, but `t()` doesn't return anything.

The second:

> 2. cannot use myfunc2 (type func(string, string) string) as type func(string, string) in argument to test1

Is pretty self-explanatory. You're trying to pass a function that returns a string `func(string, string) string`, to a function that expects a function that returns nothing `func(string, string)`.

Comment: nit: since the solution for both problems is the same (i.e. making `t` of type `func(string,string) string`, I wouldn't call them *unrelated*, right? :)